# SQLiteOpenHelp execution sequence

Tags: android, sqlite

I have code like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "IDATT.data.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 201;
    private Context mContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }
```

I wonder if onCreate/onUpgrade going to be called in `super` or after creation? Reason I ask - I need `Context` inside my onUpgrade/onCreate methods and don't know how to test this class

Comment: You can always try it, but I think that the upgrade/create is called on the first actual connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onCreate() is always called when you instantiate you class, just like those ones that extends Activity.

The onUpgrade() just gonna to be called if you pass a different DATABASE_VERSION to the super call.

Hope it helps